# How to setup a NTFS partition on an Acronis Bootable Rescue Media USB drive

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive, disk-image, acronis-trueimage

Anybody know if it's possible to partition the drive that currently has a bootable USB on it without erasing or formatting the entire USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

Windows can't handle more than one partition on a USB stick, so I'd leave well alone & buy a new stick for your NTFS drive.

Comment: That's unfortunate :/

Comment: the actual answer to your question is 'yes you can'… but not if you want windows to be able to use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

How big is your USB drive? From my experience, if your USB drive is big enough and recognised as a HDD by Windows, it is possible for Windows to handle more than one partition on a USB drive. Anyway, I don't know if this trully has something to do with the USB drive's storage size, I also heard that it is about the ports which makes Windows recognise your UBS drive in different ways. However, you may try to use the free edition of MiniTool Partition Wizard to split your USB drive or use the resize function to create the partition. I also recommend to try to hide the first partition after you created the NTFS partition to check if it works.